# How to exclude certain item in a map with a certain condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing a menu page, where users can see the menu's items based on their roles.

Currently, I have 3 pages: **Bulletin Board**, **Info Hub** and **Settings**

So naturally, I have 3 roles: **Admin Role** (can access all 3 of the pages), **Bulletin Board** (can only access Bulletin Board), **Info Hub** (can only access Info Hub)

So users can have a different roles, for example, if they have **Bulletin Board** and **Info Hub**, then they can access both of them, but not the **Settings** page (only "Admin Role" can see **Settings**), so I want to hide the **Settings** in this menu that I've already developed and rendered using `map`.

Or if the user has all 3 roles including **Admin Role**, then they can see everything as well.

I'm taking the `loginList` prop from an API and passing it into the **AllAppsCentre.js** to determine which menu items to show, but I just can't figure out the logic to do a `filter` or `indexOf` at the `map`.

In the codesandbox that I've created, the user has all 3 roles.

**AllAppsCentre.js(map function to display the menu items)**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const loginListFromParent = loginList;

    const showAll = loginListFromParent.some(
      (item) =>
        item.permissionName.includes("Admin Role") &&
        item.permissionType.includes("view")
    );

    const showBulletin = loginListFromParent.some(
      (item) =>
        item.permissionName.includes("Bulletin Board") &&
        item.permissionType.includes("view")
    );

    const showInfoHub = loginListFromParent.some(
      (item) =>
        item.permissionName.includes("Info Hub") &&
        item.permissionType.includes("view")
    );

    if (loginListFromParent) {
      setShowAll(showAll);
      setShowBulletin(showBulletin);
      setShowInfoHub(showInfoHub);
    }
  }, [loginList]);

return (
{AllAppsCentreData
   .filter((item) => {
       .map((item, index) => {
           return (
              <Col key={index} xs={6} md={3}>
                  <div className={item.className}>
                      <Link to={item.path}>
                           {item.icon}
                           <Row>
                              <span className='apps-title'>
                                 {item.title}
                              </span>
                           </Row>
                      </Link>
                  </div>
              </Col>
           )
})}
)
```

**AllAppsCentreData.js**

```
import * as IoIcons from 'react-icons/io'
import * as MdIcons from 'react-icons/md'

export const AllAppsCentreData = [
    {
        title: 'Bulletin Board',
        path: '/bulletinboard',
        icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper size={80} />,
        className: 'row text-center apps-centre-icon'
    },
    {
        title: 'Info Hub',
        path: '/infohub',
        icon: <MdIcons.MdDeviceHub size={80} />,
        className: 'row text-center apps-centre-icon'
    },
    {
        title: 'Settings',
        path: '/settings',
        icon: <IoIcons.IoMdSettings size={80} />,
        className: 'row text-center apps-centre-icon'
    },
]
```

I've been trying to figure out how to deal with this but I just couldn't think of a solution, if all else fails, I might just remove the map method and just copy and paste my **AllAppsCentreData**'s items and move it directly into the **AllAppsCentre** page instead so I can do ternary operations at the menu items.

If there is any better way to do this menu with the role-based display, feel free to let me know as I also want to learn the optimal way to do something like this.

[image: Edit affectionate-danny-qvnwj]

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

To start off, there is no variable in your code that is responsible for holding current user's permissions (or I can't see one). So I made it up:

```
const currentUsersPermissions = useGetPermissions() // get users permissions
// the above can be "admin", "bulletin" or "info-hub"
```

Then, you need to first `filter` your array and then `map` it (currently, you are using `map` inside of `filter`). To do it easier and correctly, you could add a property called `requiredPermission` (or something simillar) to your `AllAppsCentreData` objects:

```
{
    title: 'Bulletin Board',
    path: '/bulletinboard',
    icon: <IoIcons.IoIosPaper size={80} />,
    className: 'row text-center apps-centre-icon',
    requiredPermission: "bulletin" // and info-hub for Info Hub
},
```

Then, while rendering and mapping, you can do it like this:

```
return (
{AllAppsCentreData
   .filter(
       // below, you return true if permission is admin because he can see everything
       // and true or false depending if permissions are other than that but
       // the same as required by AllAppsCentreData array objects
       (item) => currentUsersPermissions === "admin" ? true : currentUsersPermissions === item.requiredPermission
   ).map((item, index) => {
       return (
          <Col key={index} xs={6} md={3}>
              <div className={item.className}>
                  <Link to={item.path}>
                       {item.icon}
                       <Row>
                          <span className='apps-title'>
                             {item.title}
                          </span>
                       </Row>
                  </Link>
              </div>
          </Col>
       )
)
```

So, to sum up:

1. I have created a variable to hold current users' permission
2. I have added a property to each AllAppsCentreData's objects, which contains info about permission required to show it
3. I have filtered the array right before mapping it and rendering, so it contains only the data I want to render
   Also, I think you are lost in using `filter` method, so perhaps read this and try doing some easier excercises to get a feeling how it works: [MDN on Array.filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). The thing you need to pay attention is that you pass a function into `filter`, and this function should return `true` or `false` depending on whether you want your item included in the output array.